# Why does the UICollectionViewUpdateItem indexPathBeforeUpdate (of type NSIndexPath?) require two !'s to unwrap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

`UICollectionViewLayout` contains a function `prepareForCollectionViewUpdates`

```
func prepareForCollectionViewUpdates(_ updateItems: [AnyObject]!) // updateItems is an array of UICollectionViewUpdateItem
```

`UICollectionViewUpdateItem` contains a property `indexPathBeforeUpdate`

```
var indexPathBeforeUpdate: NSIndexPath? { get }
```

I am looking at some code for a `CollectionViewLayout` class that is a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and Xcode is requiring two `!`'s to unwrap `indexPathBeforeUpdate` (which is a property whose getter returns an `NSIndexPath?`). It seems this would only require one `!` to unwrap. Relevant code:

```
class CollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  var insertIndexPaths = NSMutableArray()
  var deleteIndexPaths = NSMutableArray()

  override func prepareForCollectionViewUpdates(updateItems: [AnyObject]!) {
       super.prepareForCollectionViewUpdates(updateItems)

      deleteIndexPaths.removeAllObjects()
      insertIndexPaths.removeAllObjects()

      for update in updateItems {
        if update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateAction.Delete {
          deleteIndexPaths.addObject(update.indexPathBeforeUpdate!!)   // <- I have a question here
        } else if update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateAction.Insert {
          insertIndexPaths.addObject(update.indexPathAfterUpdate!!)           
        }
      }
    ...
    }
  }
```

If I only use one ! to unwrap update.indexPathBeforeUpdate

```
 deleteIndexPaths.addObject(update.indexPathBeforeUpdate!)
```

I get the error:

```
Value of optional type 'NSINdexPath?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"
```

and I get a Fix-it suggestion of "Insert `!` With two `!'s` unwrapping update.`indexPathBeforeUpdate`, the code runs fine.

To investigate, I inserted some variables just inside the for loop:

```
for update in updateItems {
  var myUpdate = update  // option-click shows myUpdate is an AnyObject
  var indexPath1 = update.indexPathBeforeUpdate    // option-click shows indexPath1 is an NSIndexPath?!
  var indexPath2 = update.indexPathBeforeUpdate!   // option-click shows indexPath2 is an NSIndexPath?
  var indexPath3 = update.indexPathBeforeUpdate!!  // option-click shows indexPath3 is an NSIndexPath
...
}
```

Option-clicking on the variables shows the types in the comments above for each one.

Why does Xcode require two `!`'s to unwrap `update.indexPathBeforeUpdate` when the documentation for `UICollectionViewUpdateItem` shows `indexPathBeforeUpdate` to be an Optional `NSIndexPath` (`NSIndexPath?`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how when you pull up the auto completion for `update` in your for-in loop property it could return is an Optional? That's because you're working with an array of `[AnyObject]`. Swift can't guarantee the object will have the property you're asking for, so it wraps it in an Optional.

If you cast that array, you don't have the double unwrapping issue (or at least you have moved the first force unwrap into the cast).

```
for update in updateItems as! [UICollectionViewUpdateItem] {
    if update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateAction.Delete {
        deleteIndexPaths.addObject(update.indexPathBeforeUpdate!)
    } else if update.updateAction == UICollectionUpdateAction.Insert {
        insertIndexPaths.addObject(update.indexPathAfterUpdate!)
    }
}
```

I'm guessing Apple has not had time to audit this API yet. In the future I'd expect the method signature to change to:

```
override func prepareForCollectionViewUpdates(updateItems: [UICollectionViewUpdateItem])
```

which will make this a non-issue. For now it's just something we have to deal with.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestions and explanations and I get it now.